Is it okay to ask for opinions here that relate to a question on a different SE site?
Question
LEGO-related questions sometimes appear on Worldbuilding SE. I know this because I have posted them occasionally myself.
I currently have two such questions. I'm wondering if it will be okay to:
(a) Ask a supplementary question here that will get me some extra information
(b) Somehow 'advertise' here that I would like help from this expert community. You might say that this question itself is such an advertisement! There is some truth in this but it is not all the truth.
For those who are interested, I'll post the links but hide them to avoid being too blatant.

 https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/184560/lego-as-a-defence-against-barefoot-warriors


 https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/184565/is-it-possible-to-melt-and-accurately-mould-lego-plastic-using-only-neolithic-te

I have other LEGO Worldbuilding question going back awhile.

You can certainly ask questions here related to your questions elsewhere, but as with all questions on Stack Exchange, please ensure that they are good, standalone questions ;)
For example your second question (which seems to have some great answers already, thankfully which didn't appear to harm any actual LEGO) might also already be answered in part by Damage Boiling LEGO Bricks noting the melting point of ABS in general.
